# Why do I have to give a name to a subquery when using COUNT?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For the following query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT codEst FROM
  inscripciones WHERE codCur = 9
) cantEstudiantes;
```

If I remove the naming for the subquery (cantEstudiantes) it will give an error. Why do I have to name the subquery although I am not using that name for nothing ?

Comment: Always give an alias for the SubQuery.

Comment: Asking "why" when it comes to programming isn't particularly useful.  Why do you want to know?   It's like asking "why do I have to use SELECT instead of GET?

Comment: You have to name the subquery because that's part of the syntactical definition.  Why does it bother you to type a name?

Comment: Alias is a must for a sub query. This is like a table name and you can not stop writing a script just after - "SELECT * FROM", A table name is required.

Comment: The simplest answer is that "Those Are The Rules."

Comment: no need for a subquery here anyway, you can just do `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT codEst) FROM
  inscripciones WHERE codCur = 9`

Comment: In oracle derived tables dont require aliases. Not sure if there is any specific reason for requiring them in the TSQL grammar

Comment: @MartinSmith That would work, but if `codEst` can contain a `null` then it would have to be accounted for, since it will be excluded from the count.

Comment: You are using   FROM () the clause FROM require the table  name  ..

Comment: @Shawn true....

Comment: @scaisEdge Agree, and it's the rules nothing more, it may be different from a DBMS to another.

Comment: It's a ms sql server sintax. You can use just a `c` (instead of `cantEstudiantes`) if you are that tired.

Comment: @sami .. the FROM()  clause require always  a table name  ..  is SQL not DB related  SQL

Comment: @scaisEdge not in Oracle. See this Q for example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36485734/oracle-sql-derived-table-optional-aliasing

Comment: @MartinSmith see also the answer

Comment: I've seen the answer. that in no way backs up your point that it is "always required". The OP here could do what they want in Oracle https://rextester.com/MDCPW87602

Comment: It's not required in Oracle, but I wouldn't be surprised if Oracle does it behind the scenes. Otherwise, you wouldn't be able to reference the columns from the subselect.

Comment: it's a `derived table` not a subquery

Answer (score 0):

Derived tables are not the same as a temporary or physical tables where the fields and data types are declared. Nor are they subqueries. Instead, as the name implies, the table is derived from an existing table. I liken them to views but a view is an object that is created and is re-usable. A derived table is only available at execution time and not a re-usable object within the query. In other words, you cannot reference it multiple times like you can with common table expressions (CTE’s).

http://dbadiaries.com/t-sql-derived-tables-demonstrated-and-explained/

Answer (score 0):

The technique you are using is called "derived table". Every table, even the derived table, has to have a name. That is why you can't omit it.